# Is a statement near AdSense ads saying "sorry about the ads" against policy?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

A site is using Google AdSense under "Our Sponsors" heading.  I know this is acceptable by Google AdSense policy.

A few more lines were added above every ad like,"**Sorry to tired you with ads! But as we are FREE we had to cover our fees!!**"  (sentence changed)

I think that this is a type of request for the users to click those ads. (It made me click.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the relevant sections of the [AdSense policy](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en):

> ### Misleading labels
>
> Directly or indirectly encouraging users to click Google ads is not permitted by our program policies. For instance, publishers may not place ads under misleading headers or titles as this may confuse users into thinking the ads are actually site links related to that header. To avoid this issue, we ask that publishers use only "sponsored links" or "advertisements" to label ads.
>
> Publishers should not use:
>
> - “Sponsor”
> - “Recommended”
> - “Partners”
> - “Offers”
> - “links”
> - “News”
> - "My favorite sites"
> - "Latest news"
>
> ### Misleading to clicks
>
> Publishers are not allowed to use language to lead users to click Google ads, such as:
>
> - "Feel free to click an ad"
> - "Contribute to the cause, visit an ad"
> - "Help keep this site running, check out our sponsors"
> - "We need a new server. Support us!"

Even the "our sponsers" language being used is against policy.   Only "sponsored links" or "advertisements" are permitted.

The "sorry about the ads" statement is very similar to the specific examples disallowed under the "Misleading to clicks" section.   It is not as direct as some of the examples, but their policy also prohibits indirectly encouraging users to click the ads.

Answer (score 2):

Anything that causes unnatural clicking of ads by visitors is prohibited by Google Adsense. Wording will not matter always.

So yes in your case, it won't be allowed.